# How to get specific key value pairs form array of objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am working with a object array in JavaScript and i want to output the code in a specific format i.e to remove the object array and created it like a array only and remove rest of the parameters.

```
 purchase_roas: [
            {
               action_type: "omni_purchase",
               value: "29.650019"
            }
         ],
```

The output I need is in this format:
`purchase_roas:29.650019`

I tried using map function but the output is not the expected one.
I used the code below:

```
for (var number in purchase_roas) {
  if (purchase_roas.hasOwnProperty(number)) {
    keys.push(number);
  }
}
```

The output i am getting is ["0"]

Comment: Can the `purchase_roas` array have more than one object in it?

Comment: the purchase_roas cannot have more than one object. The reason for this restriction is because if i get the purchase_roas:29; in this format it will be easier for me to output the data in google sheets.

Comment: Then simply `data.purchase_roas = data.purchase_roas[0].value` ..?

Comment: Hey your method is working and i am getting the expected value too. Thanks for the help @Teemu

Comment: Please be clearer next time. If Teemu's comment is what you need, then it was extra trivial.

Comment: Hey mplungjan sorry the mistake but the output code i needed is to used inside a automation software where everything is predefiend like slice function map function there i cant write a single piece of code. Due to this reason i was confused and restricted to specific pre defined codes.